# UV interpolation gets distorted on a trapezoid

Tags: textures, webgl, uv-mapping, interpolation

I'm experiencing an interesting distortion in the UV mapping of a trapezoid. When I map a square plane and tilt it backwards, the [perspective-correct interpolation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/71478/107270) gives it the expected pinching at the top, and stretching at the bottom. However, when I scale up the base of a square to make a trapezoid, my UV interpolation shows a noticeable break along the diagonal where the two faces meet:

[image]

I've created [a working example to demonstrate this effect in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marquizzo/c1pvwdbg/). You can rotate the camera to notice the trapezoid doesn't tilt back, so perspective shouldn't really affect the interpolation.

Does this behavior have a name? If so, is there any known solution to it?

Comment: We have some [past Q&A about how to fix these types of diagonal artifacts of affine texturing on tapered geometry](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/148082/39518?). Give that a shot, and if you have any issues adapting the answer there to your needs, edit your question to clarify where you're stuck and we can re-open it for answers to help you overcome that specific obstacle.